# Only load image that will be used with responsive layout

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to take advantage of Bootstrap 3's responsive utilities to only load a certain image based on the size of the device used:

```
<img src="http://bit.ly/12VMi5H" class="img-thumbnail visible-lg .hidden-print">
<img src="http://dell.to/12VMrWX" class="img-thumbnail visible-md .hidden-print">
<img src="http://bit.ly/12VMu55" class="img-thumbnail visible-sm .visible-print">
```

HOWEVER, I don't want to have to load all 3 images. How can I via CSS or some other lightweight means only load the appropriate image for that device and screensize?

Answer (score 1):

If you load images via CSS as background images, you can control what assets gets loaded via the appropriate media query. Unlike HTML, loading the image via CSS will only load the appropriate image based on what the viewport is. You can assign a specific background image at each breakpoint. Below is an example based on BS 3.0.

HTML:

```
   <div class="image-holder></div>
```

CSS:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {

  .image-holder {
  background: #fff url(http://bit.ly/12VMu55) no-repeat ; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {

  .image-holder {
  background: #fff url(http://dell.to/12VMrWX) no-repeat ; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {

  .image-holder {
  background: #fff url(http://bit.ly/12VMu55) no-repeat ; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  }
}
```

If you want another sized image just for mobile, put it into the main body of the css as BS is mobile-first.

Comment: I think he's looking for clarification about whether or not this would only download the asset as needed via breakpoints and not just loading all 3 unnecessarily. add reference to that and I'll up vote

Comment: Thanks this a very useful idea but Kai's point, will the images still be loaded in this case? Also, could we have the media tag defined to use the bootstrap class for sizing instead of explicit sizing? for example @media (.visible-sm)

Comment: I edited per Kai's feedback. In a nutshell since the CSS loads after the HTML you can control what image gets loaded for the div via media queries. If you do it this way there is no need for the responsive utilities, as you are accomplishing the same thing.

Comment: .visible-sm= Visible for width of 768-991 pixels, .visible-md= Visible for width of 992-1200 pixels,.visible-lg= Visible for width of 1200 pixel and beyond

Comment: thx. is there a way to combine these so the mobile and tablet use hte same image size? like @media (min-width: 768px && min-width: 992px)

Comment: OK i found the answer on bootstrap's site on how not to hard code the px values for detection (i can't put @ in here but it is implied)
/* Small devices (tablets, 768px and up) */
media (min-width: @screen-sm-min) { ... }

/* Medium devices (desktops, 992px and up) */
media (min-width: @screen-md-min) { ... }

/* Large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up) */
media (min-width: @screen-lg-min) { ... }

Comment: and i found the answer to combing the media querires. for example, @media (min-width: 401px) and (max-width: 700px) {...}

Comment: There is an easier way, just add the mobile sized background image in the main css (not under any media query) and only add a different image at the 992 media query.

Answer (score 0):

Some javascript is another option here, if for any reason you prefer not to load images as `background-image` in your CSS. This option only loads the bigger file(s) when needed (but does always load the smallest one regardless):

HTML:

```
<img src="...example-image_small.jpg" />
```

Javascript:

```
if ($(window).width() > 767) {
    $("img[src$='_small.jpg']").each(function() {
        var new_src = $(this).attr("src").replace('_small', '_large'); 
        $(this).attr("src", new_src); 
    });
}
```

**[Example](http://www.bootply.com/Y8XECJpGjS)**

Make sure you've got image files named properly (ending in _small and _large) it should all fall into place.